# Centos Live Replication Setup

Tags: centos, ldap

I am trying to find the best way to perform live replication.
 I am not certain if it can replicate a whole server in real time. Lsyncd can replicate a directory. This file server is running Samba and uses  LDAP to authenticate window users. I would like to find a way to replicate 2 servers in real time. One of the server will act as a replacement if the other server dies.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider of using [GlusterFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlusterFS) which can provide you smooth and transparent sync of all the directories, shared by samba. Moreover with this distributed filesystem you can add easy and sample nodes when this is required.